# serializeTo parameter in ColumnDataClassifier

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, text-classification

I am currently performing a text classification using the ColumnDataClassifier by Stanford NLP group.
I would like to perform the training stage serializing the model through the serializeTo parameter included in the prop file.

Classification results obtained performing training and test stages through the same command line are different from those ones obtained applying the serialized classifier on a new test document. Why this happens?

Example:

**First classification**

java -cp "*:." edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier -prop myfile.prop

where in myfile.prop i added values for trainFile and testFile.

[image]

**Second classification**

java -cp "*:." edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier -prop myfile2.prop

where in myfile2.prop i added values for trainFile and serializeTo. I am not including any testFile in myfile2.prop. Once i finish the training stage i want to classify new data using the classifier serialized during the training phase.

java -cp "*:." edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier -loadClassifier MyClassifier -testFile myTestFile

[image]

As you can see results are different. In particular, the serialized classifier associates almost all the instances to the class O (the default one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i resolved the problem by myself. Writing the following line of code leads to unexpected results:

`java -cp "*:." edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier -loadClassifier MyClassifier -testFile myTestFile`

This is the right command:

`java -cp "*:." edu.stanford.nlp.classify.ColumnDataClassifier -prop file.prop -loadClassifier MyClassifier -testFile myTestFile`

In other words, the property file must be included even if it used only during the training stage.